# After Spring boot 2.2.0 upgrade cause issue to read value by placeholder

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'myname' in value "${myname}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:908) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1228) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 94 common frames omitted


@Value("${myName}")
private String myName
```

myName is value getting readed from Vault, with old Spring boot version it was worked well, Issue started after Latest upgrade

And Test Case fail with

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'linkDiscoverers' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/hateoas/config/HateoasConfigurati
on.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'linkDiscoverers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.s
pringframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry<org.springframework.hateoas.client.LinkDiscoverer, org.springframework.http.MediaType>' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: relProviderPluginRegistry,
linkDiscovererRegistry,entityLinksPluginRegistry
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry<org.springframework.hateoas.client.LinkDiscoverer, org.sp
ringframework.http.MediaType>' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: relProviderPluginRegistry,linkDiscovererRegistry,entityLinksPluginRegistry
```

Comment: can you also confirm if a property with the same name exists, in your application.properties or application.tml

Comment: myName is value getting readed from Vault, with old Spring boot version it was worked well, Issue started after Latest upgrade

Comment: assuming you can get the data from vault kv command (just checking)

Comment: Yes I am getting it from Vault using kv

Comment: Are you adding  @ConfigurationProperties on class,  not sure that will work, but that's only thing i can think of

Comment: Removed dependency from Vault and added configuration file with required properties 
but got another issue with swagger UI

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2932 May be need to wait till next compatible version release for swagger

Comment: not sure issue still persist though its open, I am using spring boot 2.2 and swagger 2.9.2 without any issue, you can see my sample project here https://github.com/KoolShailesh/simple-rest-service

Comment: Request you to please try an add 
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: added <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
  </dependency> , then ran into issue and I had to tweak my swagger connfig , as suggested on bug page, **it works**

Comment: It help's now have to resolve primary issues with Vault Secret reader

Comment: my vault runs fine, just update to spring boot 2.2.0

Comment: Now means?  What change you did

Comment: Now application is working fine but test cases failing. Didn't change anything only added code as mentioned in your code base, added error message in Question section above

Comment: probably posting a fresh question with details, plus this question URL will help, this is the thrid problem, related to your spring boot upgrade, your may not follow your thread, also it has too many discussion in comments. If below answer helped you in solving vault issue accept the same, else no problem, post a fresh question related to testing case failing, we will take from there

Comment: Thanks @ShaileshChandra questions/58682321

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, I have created a vault configuration class, and I am putting my credential like below

> vault kv put secret/gs-vault-config app.security.username=myUser
>   app.security.password=myPassword

Now wherever I want to use my vault property I inject vault configuration class

```
 @Autowired 
   private VaultConfiguration vault;
```

then the required properties can be accessed from getter method, and below is my VaultConfiguration

```
@ConfigurationProperties("app.security")
public class VaultConfiguration {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Also, you need to enable configuration properties, I added below annotation on my Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(VaultConfiguration.class)
public class Application  { ..... }
```